# How to insert weekend/holiday date between dataframe date

Tags: pandas

I try to insert weekend/holiday date between business date in DataFrame pandas. Like stock market date and close price.

In simple situation like below (example 1) works well.
But, some complicated situation (example 2) didn't works.

(Example 1) Sucsess

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2023-08-11', '2023-08-14'],
                   'close' : [177.79, 179.46],
                   'stock' : ['APPL','APPL']})
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format ="%Y-%m-%d") 

df1
# Out[7]: 
#              close stock
# date                    
# 2023-08-11  177.79  APPL
# 2023-08-14  179.46  APPL


df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1_fin = df1.reindex(pd.date_range(df1.index.min(), df1.index.max())).sort_index(ascending=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'date'})

df1_fin
#         date   close stock
# 0 2023-08-11  177.79  APPL
# 1 2023-08-12     NaN   NaN
# 2 2023-08-13     NaN   NaN
# 3 2023-08-14  179.46  APPL
```

(Example 2) Didn't work with error  `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2023-08-11', '2023-08-14','2023-08-11', '2023-08-14'],
                   'close' : [177.79, 179.46, 321.01, 324.04],
                   'stock' : ['APPL','APPL','MSFT','MSFT']})
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format ="%Y-%m-%d") 

df1
# Out[7]: 
#              close stock
# date                    
# 2023-08-11  177.79  APPL
# 2023-08-14  179.46  APPL
# 2023-08-11  321.01  MSFT
# 2023-08-14  324.04  MSFT



df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1_fin = df1.reindex(pd.date_range(df1.index.min(), df1.index.max())).sort_index(ascending=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'date'})


## ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels


# This is what I want
#         date   close stock
# 0 2023-08-11  177.79  APPL
# 1 2023-08-12     NaN   NaN
# 2 2023-08-13     NaN   NaN
# 3 2023-08-14  179.46  APPL
# 4 2023-08-11  321.01  MSFT
# 5 2023-08-12     NaN   NaN
# 6 2023-08-13     NaN   NaN
# 7 2023-08-14  324.04  MSFT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate items due to `stock`. You can pivot the `stock` to columns:

```
(df1.pivot(index='date',columns='stock')   # pivot stock to columns so `date` is unique
    .resample('D').first()                 # resample
    .stack(level='stock',dropna=False)     # put `stock` back as index
    .sort_index(level=['stock','date'])    # sort the data
    .reset_index()                         # make the index normal columns again
)
```

Output:

```
        date stock   close
0 2023-08-11  APPL  177.79
1 2023-08-12  APPL     NaN
2 2023-08-13  APPL     NaN
3 2023-08-14  APPL  179.46
4 2023-08-11  MSFT  321.01
5 2023-08-12  MSFT     NaN
6 2023-08-13  MSFT     NaN
7 2023-08-14  MSFT  324.04
```

**Note**: There is a `close: NaN` row for each missing pair of `date, stock` rather than a duplicate `stock: NaN, close: NaN` for each missing `date, stock`